# Which superheroes are *really* the most popular?

Tags: super-hero

It's pretty common to hear people to claim that Batman, Superman and Spiderman are the most popular superheroes. However, with the probable exception of Batman, lately, due to movies and other factors, it seems like other superheroes may be surpassing them in terms of popularity.

Have there been any legitimate studies on who the most popular superheroes are in different parts of the world? If so, what were their results? I would define popularity and terms of how well-known and liked they are.

Comment: You might have to narrow down on what you define "most popular" as. Do you mean which superhero is *trending* right now? https://www.google.com.au/trends/explore#q=batman%2C%20Superman%2C%20deadpool%2C%20wolverine%2C%20spiderman&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-11

Comment: Exactly: how do you define most popular? Do you mean who has the most comic series on the shelf right now? Who is selling the most comics? Who is selling the most toys? Who is being mentioned on the internet the most? Who people subjectively like more? Who has shown up in more movies? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 10):

In India, it is pretty much Batman rage, atleast since Early 2008.

Batman and Spiderman are the [Indian favourites since the dawn of superheroes](https://www.google.co.in/trends/explore#q=Batman%2C%20Superman%2C%20Spiderman%2C%20Krrish%2C%20Shaktimaan&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-5%3A30). Superman has gained a bit of popularity, after the recent announcement of blockbusters, but that was very minimal when compared to how Batman is trending.

> [image]

And another surprising result: **[Hulk is more popular in India over Ironman](https://www.google.co.in/trends/explore#q=Batman%2C%20Superman%2C%20Spiderman%2C%20Ironman%2C%20Hulk&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-5%3A30)**.

> [image]

So, Batman survived blockbusters like [Krrish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krrish) and easily trumps India's most popular superhero, [Shaktimaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaktimaan).

And Batman sure enough is [the world's favourite superhero](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=Batman%2C%20Superman%2C%20Spiderman%2C%20Ironman%2C%20Hulk&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-5%3A30), according to Google trends, very distantly followed by Superman.

> [image]

---

As a footer note, I would like to include that Pokemon trends almost as much as 2 times more than Batman in the Asian countries. So, if he comes under the category of superheroes, then is Ash Ketchum the winner?

Comment: Depending on how the underlying search algorithm works, these results may or may not be misleading.  The official spellings of those characters' names are "Spider-Man" and "Iron Man".  Also, "hulk" and "superman" may also be used as generic terms.